# CompletionStage: Return a CompletionStage within exceptionally block

Tags: java, java-8, promise, completable-future

Is there a way to return a new `CompletionStage` if an Exception occurs?

The API for `exceptionally`, doesn't seem to allow you to do that. Is there a way around this?

Essentially I'd like to do `flatMap` (`thenCompose`) for the `exceptionally` case

```
public CompletionStage<String> cleanupTask() {
  //DO something long running
}

public CompletionStage<String> workThatCanFail() {
  //Some long running task that may fail
}

public void action() {

CompletionStage<String> work = 
    workThatCanFail()
    .exceptionally(throwable -> cleanupTask());

}
```

Comment: difficult to understand your problem. Could you please write your problem in more detail

Comment: @sankyjain added an edit

Comment: The JDK8 `CompletableFuture` is so terrible. Missing these helpful idioms

Comment: If `workThatCanFail()` leaves things that need cleanup in the exceptional case, that method should initiate/perform the cleanup itself instead of relying on the caller to chain a cleanup action.